# Cannot connect with cURL and www-authenticate: Negotiate

Tags: curl, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I'm trying to connect to MS Dynamics NAV WebServices.

I'm using cURL

I'm making a request like

`curl http://server/NAV80/WS/CRONUS%20Company/Page/CustomerList -v --negotiate -u NAV\Test:T3st`

And in the response I get

```
> GET /NAV80/WS/CRONUS%20Company/Page/CustomerList HTTP/1.1
> Host: x.x.x.x:x
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : unknown mech-code 0 for mech unknown
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 14:47:44 GMT
```

I keep getting 401 although setting either `--negotiate` or `--ntlm` parameter. How to connect properly to make auth successful?

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What does this have to do with Dynamics CRM?

Comment: Try to change the Dynamics NAV Service Tier to [Use NTLM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from/). Many non Microsoft Solutions have trouble the Kerberos Authentication.